# How to choose a good model based on validation and train error?

Tags: cross-validation

Here is a question:

> Is it true that: A classifier that attains 100% training accuracy and
>   70% test accuracy is better than a classifier that attains 70%
>   training accuracy and 75% test accuracy

Answer (score 2):

Probably not? 100% training accuracy is often a sign of overfitting - you've trained the model to perfectly identify your training data, which means it is likely to perform poorly on data that doesn't resemble that which it was trained on, which is shown in the fact that it doesn't do quite so well on the test data.

Comment: How about the other case where the training data performs worse than the validation set?

Comment: The training error is uninteresting. You can always bring it up to 100%. Models should only be evaluated and compared using hold-out sets. In both cases, the classifier with better performance on test is to be preferred.